# Unable to change runtime environment on server in Liferay Developer Studio

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

In Liferay Developer Studio, I am try to set the Runtime Environment for my local server. After selecting a runtime environment from the drop down, I then try to save the change and get the following message:

> The server cannot be saved for the following reasons: [Overview] Changing runtime base directories is not supported.

Is this a change I need to do manually in a configuration file, or should I going elsewhere to change the runtime environment?

[image: Liferay Server Overview]

[image: Error Message When Saving]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the existing runtime evironment changed.

I first had to go to the server properties and select "Switch Location". This moved the server properties from "[workspace metadata] to my workspace/servers/ directory.

Inside the .server file, I just had to change the runtime-id property to one of my predefined runtimes, in my case...

```
runtime-id="Liferay v6.2 EE (Tomcat 7)"
```

My Liferay server is now working as expected.

[image: Server Properties]

[image: Server Overview]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a known issue in Liferay IDE, check [the issue](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-243).

You may have a clean version of the Liferay-Tomcat bundle given along with the Liferay IDE. What I recommand you is to create a new server that refers to this runtime environnement.

If you don't have a clean version of the Liferay-Tomcat bundle you can download new one from [Liferay official site.](https://www.liferay.com/fr/downloads)